# How to partition my hard disk while installing ubuntu and don't lose data on d,e&g drive?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, installation, disk-space

This is how my current disk partition  looks:

[image]

this is how my current hard disk image looks like on windows 7. I am installing Ubuntu 17.04 from USB stick. I cannot understand how to partition the disk so as to not loose the data in my d,e and g drives. the drive c data doesn't matters to me.Please tell how to utilise free space as that was my f drive and I deleted that already due to some reasons.Please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

As you have created the free space, only use the freespace while installing the OS. You'll be asked if you want to install the OS

1. alongside
2. erase everything and install
3. one more(I don't remember)
4. something else

Here, choose "4. something else" and create the new OS partitions manually(allotting space for / , /home, /swap ), by selecting the freespace(you can find more than one freespace look for the size equivalent that you have created)this prevents from loosing any data.

Here's the [link](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/) for entire dualboot procedure and how to create partitions with freespace created. This procedure is similar be it windows8/8.1/10